# Magento 2.2: How to show a cutomer custom attribute on frontend?

Tags: magento2, attributes, frontend, backend

I need to show my custom attribute in the next windows:

On the **address book**:

[image]

On the **checkout page**:
[image]
[image]

And in the **backend** customer edit:
[image]

> It is possible assign the attribute with XML file without edit all the
>   phtml files?